# Solutions to a second-degree DE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $y_1,y_2$ are solutions to a differential equation $y''-ty'+3y=t$.
> Which of the following functions are also the solutions?
>
> a) $y_1+y_2$
>
> b) $5y_1$
>
> c) both of them
>
> d) none of them

I think the solutions is none of them, but I am not sure and not sure how to verify it in general. Can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for b), you can check:

$$5y_{1}'' - 5ty_{1}' + 15y_{1} = 5(y_{1}'' - ty_{1}' + 3y_{1}) = 5t \ne t,$$ so we know that $5y_{1}$ is not a solution.  You can use a similar procedure to check a).